# What does "top-level evaluation" mean?

Tags: evaluation, expression-evaluation, evaluation-strategy

What does "top-level evaluation" mean?

This term was not defined in the text it was mentioned in. I do not want to tell the specific context, because I am interested only in generic explanations.

Answer (score 0):

It might have multiple meanings depending on the context, but I think it means the evaluation of the top-level expression. For example, the entire body of the `main` function in a Haskell program, is one expression (of type `IO ()`) and is the top-level expression of the program, so evaluating that expression would constitute top-level evaluation.